# Tags Социолингвистика и Sociolinguistics - are not synonyms yet

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Both tags are synonyms, but they are not marked as such. Both have 3 questions tagged with one of them. Can someone make them synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the catch. We don't always know what the tag situation is and it's useful to have other users help the moderators to clean/fix the site, tags included.

Tag synonyms have now been created and merged. If someone uses [sociolinguistics](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociolinguistics), it will be replaced by the Russian equivalent.

Comment: also [noun] and [существительные], [род] and [gender]

Comment: ...and [grammar] and [грамматика]